# Spring boot -Open api 3 doc generation dynamically without maven and restarting application (swagger Interceptor implementation)

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, swagger-codegen, swagger-inspector

I am using spring boot in which I wanted to dynamically generate open api 3 specification by uploading json/yml and view in swagger ui

1. upload json/yml
2. dynamically generate swagger /open api specification
   3.view in swagger ui

Is there any approach /plugin available to implement this?
similar implementation as swagger Interceptor but our workstation does not  allow to use interceptor. so we are generating our own tool

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic generation of openapi specification? You can generate and host the swagger documentation in the application but not sure about what
 exactly is your requirement here.

Comment: Hi My requirements is when I upload any json with valid swagger or yml from ui it has to display the respective endpoints in swagger ui and run the server endpoints all these should done through springboot code  how to implement this kindly help

Comment: So basically you want your endpoints in swagger ui which can be used to execute the rest API ? It can be done using spring code and when you run your application the swagger ui will generate the endpoints and it will display it to you. But I don't think there is any uploading of json yaml functionality is there, you can generate it from source code.

Comment: Yea I don't have source code I have only the json and I want to generate specification dynamically. The approach I'm using is 1.add the json under resource folder 2.pick the json from resource folder using maven clean build. 3.After this step it will generate the specification and4. Restart 5.show in springboot swagger ui. Instead of doing all these manually how do I automate by allowing multiple jsons . 1. Add json based on one endpoint say upload json 5.show in swagger ui (2,3,4 -automate)